# Installing python3 on CentOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, centos, environment-variables

I am using CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)) remotely (hosting my server that I would want to run python script on) which has python2 initially installed.

I install python3 instead, however, it appears both versions' PATH isn't recognized:

```
$python
-bash: python: command not found
$python --version
-bash: python: command not found
$which python
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

$python3
-bash: python3: command not found
$which python3
/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

$python3.7 -V
Python 3.7.2
```

Strange..? Python3 is indeed installed, PATH not recognized. Running script file (with `#!/usr/bin/python`) isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly put the python path on top of the script, just doing `python3.7 code.py` should suffice

Comment: I am installing python on remote machine (CentOS) so I can remotely run python scripts (my script file points to `#!/usr/bin/python`), but can´t locate python interpreter.

Comment: /usr/bin/python points to which python? Do “ls -la /usr/bin/python”

Comment: `ls -la /usr/bin/python`
`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 24 Apr 16 09:53 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python`

Comment: `/usr/bin/python -V` what does this give you

Comment: `ls -la /etc/alternatives/python``
`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 Apr 16 09:53 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python3.7`

Comment: `/usr/bin/python -V
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: So which is your original python binary location? do `which python` and `which python3.7`

Comment: `$which python
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)`

and then....
`$which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: Then your python3 is python3.7, and you don't seem to have python2 installed

Comment: So `$echo $PATH /usr/local/bin/`sets the path to my python3?

Comment: you already have the path for python3.7 `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: Oh, so mean any script file I write now should begin with `#!/usr/local/bin/` Or should be `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: You don't need to add any such line in the start of script, just run the code using `python3.7 code.py`

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer to reflect that. please upvote and accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

On my Centos7 machines, there's is no `python3` binary, it's just a symlink to the `python3.4` binary

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python3*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Jan 10  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4*
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6.0K Dec 12  2017 /usr/bin/python3.4*
```

Seems like maybe you deleted the symlink, or it was never created. Since it sounds like you have root, just recreate it.

You can run `python3.7` so first of all find out where that is: `which python3.7`

Then go to that folder and do `sudo ln -s python3.7 python3`

Comment: `$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3*
ls: /usr/bin/python3*: No such file or directory` How do I recreate it?

Comment: Updated my reponse

Comment: `$cd /usr/local/bin/``
`$ls`
`2to3-3.7  docker-compose  easy_install-3.7  idle3.7  pip3.7  pydoc3.7  python3.7  python3.7m  python3.7m-config`

`$pwd
/usr/local/bin`

`$sudo ln -s python3.7 python3`
`$cd`
`$python --version
-bash: python: command not found`